# Detatch a mdi child form from its parent?

Tags: vb.net, mdichild, mdiparent

I program using vb.net. my question relates to mdi child/ parent forms. I have a form which when viewed is a child form. The children form is in fact a client to a tcp server and needs to run at all times the patent form in contrast dose not. The problem is when I close the parent form I also close the child form resulting in issues relating to lost connections with its tcp server. Is there a way that I can move the forms outside the parent form in an invisible state thus keeping it running. Then close the parent mdi form as desired?

Comment: Given that you made it a child by setting the `MdiParent` property in the first place, did you bother trying just clearing that property?  I've never tried it myself but it seems a blatantly obvious first step.

Comment: Also, it seems like a faulty design you describe.  A more sensible option would be to have a non-UI object be the always-alive thing that maintains the connection and you could then refer to it in any form you want at any time.  You can then close the child form without issue and open another later as required.  Forms are supposed to be the user interface of your application.  The guts of the app should not be in forms but in objects referred to by forms.

Comment: This is a very odd UI design, the MDI parent ought to always be the main window and closing it automatically terminates the process.  It is however technically possible, Winforms supports setting the MdiParent property back to Nothing.  Pretty magical ability, implemented by actually destroying the native child window and re-creating it with new styles.  Preventing the app from terminating is now the harder problem to solve, you'd have to use Sub Main as the entrypoint.

Comment: It's also possible for me to reinstate the visibility of the form within the Mdi parent form and have my tcp client form visually appear but not as an mdi child, it just looks out of place. The UI design might sound odd  but it's functionality is used by the programme internally from the moment the app is launched and for statistical reasons can be called up for viewing by a human user afterward in a backed UI  (which is the mdi parent ). Re-creating the form is something I already looked at but then the temporary data placed by the app it's self is cleared also